# Azure Release Pipeline: Can I deploy to multiple servers, each with a different web.config transform applied, with a single stage.?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipline, with one artifact and multiple IIS website deployment stages.  I have multiple stages for the sole reason that the web.config transform uses the stage name to transform.  Everything in the stage is exactly the same.

I need to deploy the same web app to 3 different servers.  For each server I need to apply a different web.config transform.

Is there any way to do this in a single stage?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Release Pipeline: Can I deploy to multiple servers, each with a different web.config transform applied, with a single stage.?

Now, Both the [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) and [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) are support [file transforms and variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops).

The File Transformation will look for and apply a `*.<environment>.config` transform file where `<environment>` matches the Azure Pipeline environment for which the task is executing.

Variable Substitution will apply the value of any pipeline variables to the corresponding connectionStrings or appSettings entries where the name matches the variable name.

Besides, there are also some other tasks can apply transform for config file, so the easy way is that you can include/add the related configure files in release artifact, then configure transform per to release environments.

[XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform)

[Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

[Tokenization task](https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)